# PHP session - Attach a class instance

Tags: php, class, session

For a small personnal project, I need to attach a class instance into a PHP Session.
For that, I've written the following code, but it doesn't work as I expect. For example, when I call the method `login` and I refresh the page, nothing is modified in my class. I mean, it's like if it was reseted everytime.

My question is: How could I share the Core instance between my pages using PHP sessions ?

```
    <?php

class Core
{
    /* Database */
    private $db = null;

    /* User activity */
    private $loggedin = false;
    private $userid = 0;
    private $username = null;
    private $password = null;
    private $lastActivity = null;

    /* Constructor */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }

    /* Serialize */
    public function __sleep()
    {
        return array('loggedin', 'userid', 'username', 'password', 'lastActivity');
    }

    /* Unserialize */
    public function __wakeup()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }

    /* Connect to database */
    private function connect()
    {
        global $DB_HOSTNAME, $DB_BASENAME, $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD;

        try
        {
            $this->db = $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$DB_HOSTNAME.';dbname='.$DB_BASENAME.';charset=utf8', $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /* Get database */
    public function getDb()
    {
        return $this->db;
    }

    /* Create a new login session */
    public function login($userid, $username, $password)
    {
        $this->loggedin = true;
        $this->userid = intval($userid);
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->lastActivity = time();
    }

    /* Close the login session */
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->loggedin = false;
        $this->userid = 0;
        $this->username = null;
        $this->password = null;
    }

    /* Check if the session is running or not */
    public function isConnected()
    {
        if ($this->loggedin)
        {
            if ($this->lastActivity + 3600 < time())
            {
                $this->logout();
                return false;
            }
            elseif (isset($this->password))
            {
                $db = $this->db;
                $query = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM ptc_users WHERE id=:userid AND password=:password LIMIT 1;');
                $query->bindParam(':userid', $this->userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $query->bindParam(':password', $this->password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->execute();

                if ($query->rowCount() == 1)
                {
                    $this->lastActivity = time();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /* Return the current user id */
    public function getUid()
    {
        return $this->userid;
    }

    /* Return the current username */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /* Return the hash signature of the password */
    public function hash($input)
    {
        return sha1('minad8rBxu' .$input. 'MigdVKXUCf');
    }

    /* Return the user's ip */
    public function getIp()
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        else return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
}

// Create a new core session if not started before
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['core']))
{
    $core = new Core();
    $_SESSION['core'] = serialize($core);
}
else
{
    $core = unserialize($_SESSION['core']);
}

?>
```

I'm using the magic methods `__sleep` and `__wakeup` to avoid to serialize the PDO instance.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate or autoload the Core class so you can use it throughout your application. No need for session..Or just save the class name to session..

Just save  username, timestamp, userid and password to the session..

```
    $_SESSION['instance'] = json_encode(array('username', 'timestamp', 'userid','password'));

$object = json_decode($_SESSION['instance']);

echo var_dump($object);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you explain please ?

Comment: Dude i never heard anyone did save the instance to the session. What they do is just use the spl_autoload function

Comment: Well, I need to pass the username, timestamp, userid and password on everypage to check if the user is connected or not. That's why I need to store an instance into a session. And this is not the first time I see that. If you google it, many people are doing that.

Comment: Just save  username, timestamp, userid and password to the session..

$_SESSION['instance'] = json_encode(array('username', 'timestamp', 'userid','password'));